# Filtering a text query using $text operator

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using MongoDB v2.6.0rc-0, primarily for its full-text search capabilities. I upgraded from the dev release of 2.5.5, and the first thing 2.6.0 told me was that the `text` command was being deprecated, and I should use the `$text` query operator instead.

The documentation for the [`$text` query operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text) doesn't describe how one would run a sub-query filter, as one could with the [`text` command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/text/).

Does anyone know if it's still possible with this command or will I have to pare down my resultset programmatically?

Thanks

Comment: It is just a query operator, to run a subquery just join it as you would with other operators, literally it is like $in or anything else

Comment: Right, thanks. If you enter it as an answer, I can accept it.